# f.label within Rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently using two forms in my rails app, one for a contact form and the other is for a login form. They both use f.label in their syntax which for example is the colour white.

I would like the text to be white on one and black on the other. Normally I would just create a class and then use the relevant ID but am unsure what to do in this case with the f.label. I could use In-line styling but then that defeats the object of CSS.

Has anyone dealt with this issue previously?

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify ID for each form, and then specify styling in your CSS file.

```
#login_form label {
  color: #fff;
}

#contact_form label {
  color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, don't know why I didn't try this